# How to find the inverse of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, vector-analysis

I have a linear transformation which is defined as

$$H:\mathbb{R_{≤ 2}[x]} \to \mathbb{R^{2,2}} \ ; \ ax^2+bx+c \to 
\left[       \begin{array}{cc}       b-a& b+c  \\       a-b & b  \\        \end{array}\right]$$

and how am I supposed to find the inverse of $H$? I can calculate an inverse of an $n,m$ matrix and I'm guessing that I'm supposed to make an augmented matrix from the matrix but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the range is of the form $$\pmatrix
{A&B\\-A&C}$$ so that it is $3-$dimensional.  Also, we have $$
b=C\\
c=B-C\\
a=-A+C
$$

Answer (score 0):

The domain is of dimension $3$, the codomain of dimension $4$, therefore there is no **inverse** strictly speaking.

However, you map is injective, which means that it has a **left inverse**:$$\exists\ g\ |\ g\circ f=\operatorname{Id}_{\Bbb R_{\leq 2}[X]}$$
which means that given $f(P)$ you are able to find out what $P$ was.

**Hint:** given $f(P)$ it is quite easy to get what $b$ was, and therefrom what were the other two coefficients: $$g\left(\left[\matrix{A&B\\C&D}\right]\right)=\ldots x^2+Dx+\ldots$$